# ActiveRecord Hash form to say update_all("prio = prio + 200")

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to change attributes of a lot of records via update_all. 
The user should be able to change the prio relatively (record 1 has prio 0, record 2 prio 200, the user can choose to give them +200 so they end up with prio 200 and 400 respectively).
*and* change other columns at same time.
The preferred way in rails is

```
Model.update_all(name: name)
```

but for prio I have only the string form that I am aware of right now -

```
Model.update_all("prio = prio + #{change_of_prio}")
```

How can I change the latter into the Hash-Form of rails? Or, how can I do both in one `update_all` statement (without loosing the advantage of rails doing the necessary escaping when calling it with a Hash)?

Comment: i don't see a hash here: `"prio = prio + #{change_of_prio}"`

Comment: yes. this would be one solution of the problem. If I want to say `"name = #{name}"` i can write `{name: name}`, but how can I bring `"prio = prio + #{change_of_prio}"` in the form of a hash so I can do both in the same `update_all` call?

Comment: what's wrong with: `Model.update_all(prio: (prio + change_of_prio))`

Comment: from where do you get the `prio` value?

Comment: if you write Model.update_all("prio = prio + #{change_of_prio}"), then prio is just what's in the db for the record at the moment

That's key to know what the question is about actually.. to alter the attribute absolut, not relative to what the current value of prio is, is no problem anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have to use array notation. This would work:

```
Model.update_all(["prio = prio + :change_of_prio, name = :name", {change_of_prio: 200, name: "foo"}])
# UPDATE `models` SET prio = prio + 200, name = 'foo'
```

`:change_of_prio` and `:name` are named placeholders referring to corresponding values in the hash. Rails handles the escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `#update_all` could be applied on enumerator to set or update all the record wot the specified values. [The examples](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all):

```
# Update all customers with the given attributes
Customer.update_all wants_email: true

# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')

# Update all books that match conditions, but limit it to 5 ordered by date
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').order(:created_at).limit(5).update_all(author: 'David')
```

So in your case the call will update all the records with the same value of the `name` variable, which is passed to the function as an argument.

```
Model.update_all(name: name) # all columnt named 'name' will have value of variable `name`
```

As for `prio`:

```
prio = ...
change_of_prio = ...
Model.update_all(prio: "#{prio} #{change_of_prio}") # all columnt named 'prio' will have value of variable concat `prio` and `change_of_prio`
```